# What is the duration of the spell Creation when used to create non-precious metals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time

I was looking at the description of the spell [Creation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/creation) in 5th Ed, and saw a gap.  It lists the duration for "Precious Metals" but not for other metals.  I thought it might be the same as stone and crystal, since they're mentioned together.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the spell description these are referred to together as "mineral objects":

> You can also use this spell to create mineral objects such as stone, crystal, or metal.

And, according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precious_metal), "Precious Metals" are the types used in currency (for 5e this includes platinum, gold, electrum, silver, copper).

Due to the description lumping of "stone, crystal, or metal" together, non-precious metals should be within the "Stone or Crystal" 12 hour duration category.